# smoke sim fades out

Tags: smoke-simulation

Im trying to sim a long smoke trail but it just fades of, or dissipates, too quickly.

I have set the Smoke Cache to 400f. The adaptive domain seem so grow but the smoke doesn't extend beyond a certain point.

Any tips greatly appreciated.

:)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in the domain to make smoke dissolve over time. Try turning that off.

Comment: In the provided screenshot the Dissolve checkbox is clearly not checked.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.